# I never get embedded files loaded with from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3, langchain

My code with from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader, with a single .txt file it works but with DirectoryLoader nothing.
Attach image of the code:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAKxn.png)
Attach image of contect of the texts:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9EeN.png)

At the beginning it gave me errors with permissions, I don't know what happened, must it be because of that? then change the permissions of the Store folder to everyone.

But when running the code it always stays loading all the time

I would really appreciate if you help me please

I need the code to embed the words of the text files in the "Store" folder but it doesn't

Like this capture:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2uoW.png)

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked for me (using `langchain==0.0.127`). Maybe try restarting the Python kernel if you're using notebooks?